# How to make HTML cells change color based on dynamic text

Tags: python, html, css

I am creating a dashboard for a game and need the cells to not only be updated with the status of services, but also change color of the cells. The backend of this is a python script which is using Flask to serve the page.

Main HTML Dashboard

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Service Dashboard</title>
    <style>
        body {
            text-align: center;
        }
        table {
            margin: auto;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        th {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .status-up {
            background-color: green;
            color: white;
        }

        .status-down {
            background-color: red;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function updateDashboard() {
            fetch('/update_dashboard')
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(html => {
                    const dashboardContainer = document.getElementById('dashboard-container');
                    dashboardContainer.innerHTML = html;
                });
        }

        setInterval(updateDashboard, 5000);  // Update every 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds)
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Service Dashboard</h1>
    <div id="dashboard-container">
        <!-- This div will be updated by JavaScript -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the part that is dynamically updating

```
<!-- dashboard_content.html -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Team</th>
        <th colspan="2">Services</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Service</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    {% for team in teams %}
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="{{ team.service_statuses|length + 1 }}">{{ team.name }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% for service in team.service_statuses %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ service.name }}</td>
        <td class="{% if service.status == 'UP' %}status-up{% elif service.status == 'DOWN' %}status-down{% endif %}">
            {{ service.status }}
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I have made sure everything maps correctly and have gotten the text to update correctly, but stuck on the color part. Admittedly, I did try ChatGPT for help first but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<td class="{% if service.status == 'UP' %}status-up{% elif service.status == 'DOWN' %}status-down{% endif %}">
    {{ service.status }}
</td>
```

Use like this